# Can't change current directory using NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([filemgr changeCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/Users/me/"] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"Cannot change current directory");
    }

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the app it say "Cannot change current directory". It is not iPhone app as you can see. It is just simple console app. 
What is wrong here ?

Comment: Are you sure the file path exists?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says [NSFileManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Changing the current working directory affects only paths created in the current process.

So I guess you would have to create that dictionary during the runtime of your app.

Answer (score 0):

`/Users/me/` is probably not in the sandbox environment of the app.
In other words, your app isn't allowed to enter this folder/directory.